# Isomorphism modulo the residual

Tags: notation, gr.group-theory

Given a group $G$ let $R(G)$ be its residual, that is the intersection of all the normal subgroups of finite index. Is there a name for the relation between $G$ and $H$ defined by $G/R(G) \cong H/R(H)$? (We thought of calling it finitely isomorphic.)

Comment: Mark I don't understand your comment. $G$ and $H$ are two distinct groups, they are not subgroups of anything common.

Comment: I see: I misread your question assuming that $H\le G$. 